# Wider screen resolution on Fedora running on Hyper-V in Windows 10

Tags: fedora, grub, resolution, hyper-v, hyper-v-manager

I'm currently running Fedora on Hyper-V of Windows 10. It is now running with 1920x1080 resolution after I edited GRUB configuration. However I failed to set it to 2560x1080 (it simply ignored this parameter), which is my screen resolution. Is it possible to do that? If not, why? And is there a list of supported resolutions?

Note: I know that I can either go for Remote Desktop or type-2 hypervisor.

Answers found so far:

1. *change it in Fedora*: no other resolution available.
2. *follow the guide for Ubuntu*: `update-grub` not found
3. *possibly Hyper-V Integration Services*: part of kernel now.

Answer (score 1):

grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="video=hyperv_fb:1024x768"

The above command works. I know that this question was posted months ago but since it is not answered yet, I am posting a solution that I found to be working.

your mileage may vary !

Comment: Does it works with 2560x1080? I know how to set it to 1024x768. See [my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46799561/4451732).

Answer (score 1):

On the host you first need to set the resolution; power down the target VM first, then:

```
Set-VMVideo -VMName "Fedora34" -HorizontalResolution 2560 -VerticalResolution 1200 -ResolutionType Single
```

Then you can use grubby to set the size to match:

```
grubby --update-kernel=ALL --args="video=hyperv_fb:2560x1200"
```

You can set the grubby resolution to any size up to the size you set on the host.

Note that at the time of writing, and for the past several years, there is a maximum possible size of VRAM possible, so you may not be able to achieve an arbitrary resolution.  This issue has more details:

See also: https://github.com/LIS/lis-next/issues/318